# How to execute the output of `ls` from the command line?

Tags: command-line, redirection

Sometimes I forget my relative paths and by the time I track down where the file, is I have typed :

```
Cris-Mac-Book-2:weird cris$ ls ../../../
Icon?       Research    Support
Cris-Mac-Book-2:weird cris$ ls ../../../Support
Fourganizical       PicoCryptical       SupportPlan.txt
MoneyProjectical    Qwontical       Testcomms
OSICAL          StanTechStatistical todo
Cris-Mac-Book-2:weird cris$ ls ../../../Support/PicoCryptical
S   cs  mini    php py  readme
Cris-Mac-Book-2:weird cris$ ls ../../../Support/PicoCryptical/py/StanTechPico.py
```

To now run this script, I find myself pressing <kbd>←</kbd> until I get back to the start of the command, then replacing `python` with `ls`.

When I do this long-hold <kbd>←</kbd> (which seems to be often) I am  always thinking, *there must be a faster way to edit the command string, or execute the previous command's output.*

So, not really qualifying as a bash superuser, I tried to *pipe* the output of ls to python, which didn't work as intended :

```
Cris-Mac-Book-2:weird cris$ ls ../../../Support/PicoCryptical/py/StanTechPico.py | python
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    ../../../Support/PicoCryptical/py/StanTechPico.py
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Cris-Mac-Book-2:weird cris$
```

So my question : how to put the `STDOUT` output of a previous command, in the argument position of a new command?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Home` key?

Comment: You know my meaning, to get to the start of the command quicker, but the Fn ← doesn't work from my Terminal. It produces a seemingly random command from history.

Comment: I guess I was unaware that Macs didn't have a dedicated `Home` key.  I apologize.

Comment: It's ok. I almost feel like it's Mac's fault. They designed out the Home key. Damn them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^ls^python` will perform your immediate need (repeat previous command, substituting `python` for the `ls`)

Comment: That is awesome!

Comment: @CrisStringfellow You are right, it is awesome!! I had no idea it was possible to do something like this.

Comment: I find `python !$` a bit easier to type if it's just to reuse the last argument. The `^foo^bar` syntax is nice if you made a typo and want to keep most of the command except for a small replacement (wherever it is)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not certain you're actually asking

> But I guess what I really want is to know how to put the STDOUT output of one command in the argument position of another command, from the command line?

I think what you might find useful is using `$_`

```
$ ls /tmp/long/path/which/contains/file
/tmp/long/path/which/contains/file
$ python $_
```

The `$_` is replaced with the final argument of the previous command you executed.

See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

However, if you really do want to use the stdout as an argument for another command, you can use `xargs` for that (see http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)

```
$ ls /tmp/long/path/which/contains/file | xargs python
```

Comment: That's awesome, and also answers it. The question is unclear and messy I will clean it up.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow Your question is really bringing some interesting answers.

Comment: Yes, anything to make *bashing* (is that the verb?), more efficient!

Answer (score 4):

Have you ever used backticks?

```
python `ls ../../../somefile`
```

Will call `python` with the output of `ls` as its argument.

Not totally sure if that is what you are asking, though.

Comment: Ah that's good. Except I want that same effect without having to cursor back to the start of the command and insert `python` before ls.

Comment: Readline key bindings recall the previous command, delete the first word, and place the insertion point ready to add 'python' using 5 keystrokes without taking your fingers from the home keys: `Ctrl-p-a-[ d`.  `Ctrl-p` previous-line `Ctrl-a` start-of-line `Ctrl-[` Escape `Esc-d` kill-word.  Esc is a substitute for Meta, `Ctrl-[` is a substitute for Esc.  Type this enough and it comes out faster than you can think...

Comment: @AndrewCrabb Jeezuz I just tried that and it was awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You can type

```
python
```

and press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd>

Pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> inserts last argument of the last command. Pressing the shortcut again goes further backwards.

EDIT: I have tested this on different Linux and OpenBSD using bash,sh,ksh,dash,zsh. It does not seams work in (t)csh. Which surprises me because I thought its a feature of readline?!

Comment: That's a cool one, too. On Mac I get this character, ≥, and not the last command. Is there any way to give a Mac terminal these bindings?

Comment: @tim you should precise where that shortcut works… @cris in shell, `!$` expands to the last argument of the previous command, so you want `python !$`

Comment: @DamienPollet Great, so I think I have !$ (last argument of previous command), $_ (last output of previous command). This is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Other than Andrew's answer, a good trick to know is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> jumps the cursor to the start of the line.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate need seems solved, but here are some solutions for your long term need of finding "*a faster way to edit the command string*".

From your example, it looks like you already have bash completion (http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php#completion) on your system, so you should be able to do the exact same thing with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, just start the command with `python` instead of `ls` then <kbd>Tab</kbd> away.

Here are some of the basic shortcuts I find myself using all the time (most work on any *nix based system, but some ... especially OS X ... can be cranky sometimes).

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>
  jumps by "words" instead of individual characters.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> jumps to the beginning of the command line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> jumps to the end of the command line
- `!!` will repeat the last command in the history (and print out what the command was)

  > `$ ls`
  >   `file1`
  >   `file2`
  >   `$ !!`
  >   `ls`
  >   `file1`
  >   `file2`
- `!$` will print the very last argument from your previous command (`$_` is mentioned above, which is bash specific, is basically the equivalent ... there, I've done it, let the debate begin)

  > `$ ls ../file.py`
  >   `file.py`
  >   `$ python !$`
  >   `python ../file.py`
  >   *`script output ...`*

For a few more great ones, see the "Keyboard Shortcuts" section on [Linux Terminal Command Reference](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/244).  Even though that page is specific to Linux Mint, the only *nix system I find unhappy with those shortcuts is OS X.

Comment: ! Tab, yes, I had forgotten how to get completion. This is excellent. Or will be once I 'integrate it into my workflow and thinking'. There are helpful. I wonder what debate you have started! Any idea why OS X term gives me beep (or in my case screen flash, since I hate the beeps) the first time I strike Tab, then it cows and yields to the 'completion' the next Tab, then back to beeping the next time, and so on?